# How to access a one of the asp.net core controller action view into an iframe using react application?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

When iam trying to access one of the asp.net core application controller view from react application, In the browser console iam getting eror like

`'Refused to display 'http://localhost:1212/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=%Home%MyIFrame%3url%TestData'  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`'

since i am decorated action method with `[Authorize] attribute`

In `startup.cs` file  was included

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){
app.UseCors(
                options => options
                   .WithOrigins(
                     "http://localhost:3000",
                 )
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`X-FRAME-OPTIONS` is a web header that can be used to allow or deny a page to be iframed. This is very important when protecting against [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attempts.

Thought it is not recommended , but if you want to change the make your application be iframed , you can try to add below config in `Configure` function of asp.net core application to set `X-Frame-Options` response header , for example:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");
    await next();
});
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: was tried the above approach but its loading the total application..                                                                                                                           
but I want to load a particular webpage(Asp.net core action view) in react js(another application) IFrame...since due to authorization iam not able to access the page.... so here i want to implement a bearer token concept in startup.cs file. I got stuck here how to implement that. Is there any good approach??

Comment: No , iframe is not recommend . And if you enable the jwt authecation in web application , you should provide jwt token as authorzation header (or query string )which is depends on your server side application , but  it's not a good idea to put a secure application in an iframe because that expose you to security issue.

Comment: Yeah I just want to test my application...How to enable the jwt authecation in asp.net core application??How to provide the jwt token as authorization??

Comment: @Gandhi , see code sample : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432821/is-it-possible-to-add-request-headers-to-an-iframe-src-request