# wrong behaviour of the dynamically populated iframe

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe

I would like to embed a web page into my web page. The page that will be embedded requires token for authentication. Instead of sending the token via query params, I would like to send it in the Authorization Header. I modified the iframe population as specified in the following code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class CustomService extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.theFrame = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token"),
            header = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
            url = "http://localhost:4000";

        axios.get(url, { headers: header })
            .then((response) => {
                let doc = this.theFrame.current.contentDocument;
                doc.open();
                doc.write(response.data);
                doc.close();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });


        return <div>
            <div>
                <iframe style={{ width: "100vw", height: "50vh" }} ref={this.theFrame} title="headers set manually for this iframe"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

When the code executes, I get the following error on the console. Even though the content of the iframe is correct, the styling has not been applied.
[image]

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you perform an HTTP request using Axios, then you get the result and put the result as a content of the iFrame. This part, even if maybe is not a good idea by itself, seems to be OK, as you wrote in your question.

Now, the HTML document you loaded in this way in your iFrame, as you said, contains some style, and the styles refers to some file that may be served by `http://localhost:4000` (unless you declared them in a `<style>` tag or unless they are served by another host).

To solve your problem you have to ensure, at least, what follows:

- Are these files protected by some kind of authentication too?
- Can these files be used inside an iFrame?
- In the HTML page you loaded, can these file be resolved by the browser?

Observations about the points you should check, in order:

- If the files are protected with the same logic of the initial request, you have to implement the same logic also for the styles files
- Check if the server that provide you the CSS have any kind of limitations in this sense
- Since you are not setting the URL of your iFrame, the CSS file `src` attribute should specify the host, or, another solution, the page should specify a base URL for the resources.

Now, back to my initial consideration, are you sure that the way you are using to solve this problem is the best and only option you have?

If the only problem is the base URL, well, simply add this tag as explained here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Thanks for your answer @emanuele-scarabattoli My goal is to send the token in the Header. I don't know any other way to solve this, if you do please share with me. Setting the URL of the iframe might be the missing part, I will check it one more time

Comment: A possible solution that you can consider, but I do not have such elements to ensure that it is feasible, is to use or to implement a proxy. But, again, this option needs to be checked.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion which is "adding base tag", it works however there is a little problem. it does applied to img tag as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base#open_graph). For the image two network requests are created, first one is to my main app and second one is to the "iframe app".