# React Native WebView : How to embed iframe with authorization header?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

Within WebView, I need to send authorization header token along with iframe src like this:

```
<WebView
    source={{
      html: '<iframe src="www.myserver.com/verifytoken.php"></iframe>',
      headers: authHeader,
    }}
/>
```

Please give me a clue how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class TestCase extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <WebView
                source={{
                    uri: xyz,
                    headers: { Authorization: abc }
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

More available here: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/18#issuecomment-534968842

**And you can add header in iframe**, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432834/10305444

Comment: Maifee UI Asad, I need to embed iframe inside custom html!

Comment: @webmastx and this should work, give it a shot

Comment: UI Asad, thanks for the answer but your answer is about sending header via uri props that I already known it should work  but my question is for the request from iframe!

Comment: @webmastx you can't do so, here is the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432834/10305444