# How to share Auth0 authentication with React Micro Frontends

Tags: reactjs, authentication, single-page-application, auth0, micro-frontend

I wonder how one could manage Auth0 authentication (lifecycle) with Micro Frontends. I am building a React SPA which has a container that contain other micro-frontends and am considering the PKCE flow. What do you think would be the most effective approach to share the authentication? I think that one approach is to inject the token to micro-frontends by the container (that handles authentication) during initialization and another approach is to share the token via cookies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you display a microsite in an iframe or HTML5 web component (or native app web view) IMO the best way would be to add a authorization HTTP request header with the JWT access token? e.g.

```
 Authorization: bearer [JWT]
```

Adding HTTP headers to iframe is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432821/is-it-possible-to-add-request-headers-to-an-iframe-src-request). Looks like it's possible, but also might be some limitations... if you do run into problems you could always add the JWT as a querystring param and convert this to HTTP header in API gw that sits in front of your back-end API... note: if you do the querystring approach you should ensure there's no PII in your access tokens (which there probably shouldn't be regardless) as this would not be encrypted in transit.