# How to add headers into iframe src?

Tags: javascript, html, django, iframe

I have html like this:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I need to add headers into src. How to do it?
My app in Django.

Comment: Does this answer your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432821/is-it-possible-to-add-request-headers-to-an-iframe-src-request

Comment: It's doen't work with "https://...."

Comment: I don’t believe https is the issue, but [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is, to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This method, worked for me

```html
<iframe title="iFrame sending additional headers"></iframe>
<script>
  async function getSrc() {
    const res = await fetch("https://httpdump.io/ze5pz/dumpyard", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        // Here you can set any headers you want
        'Accept-Language': 'en-EU'
      }
    });
    const blob = await res.blob();
    const urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute("src", urlObject)
  }
  getSrc();
</script>
```

Comment: it's doesn't work, fetch not work